# If $H\leq G$ and $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then so does $H$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, sylow-theory

Consider the following question:

> Let $H$ and $P$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. Show that the sets
> $HxP$, $x \in G$, partition $G$. By considering the action of $H$ on
> the set of left cosets of $P$ in $G$ by left multiplication, or
> otherwise, show that $$\frac{|HxP|}{|P|} = \frac{|H|}{|H \cap
>  xPx^{-1}|} $$ for any $x \in G$. Deduce that if $G$ has a Sylow
> $p$-subgroup, then so does $H$.

I was able to get to the required equality by considering the Orbit-Stabiliser Theorem and a suitable homomorphism. I am struggling to deduce the last part. What has me confused is that I do not even think its true. For example, $C_{15}$ has a subgroup of order 5. Clearly it also has a Sylow $3$ group. However, the subgroup of size $5$ can not have a Sylow $3$ group. Am I misunderstanding?

I would appreciate it if someone can clarify this for me and also explain the last deduction.

Comment: A $p$-Sylow subgroup of the finite group $G$ is a subgroup of order $p^a$, where $p^a$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$. If $G$ has order $5$ and $p=3$, then that means that a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup of order $3^0=1$.

Comment: Interesting - I never thought about this in this sense. In regards to the question, do you see a way one can make the deduction? I am confused as to how one can use the result as it can at most tell me something about the order, not about subgroups.

Comment: You want to find an $x$ such that $|H|/|H\cap xPx^{-1}|$ is not divisible by $p$; that will show that $H\cap xPx^{-1}$, which is necessarily a $p$-subgroup of $H$, is in fact a Sylow $p$-subgoup of $H$. To show that, you want to show that there exists an $x$ such that $|HxP|/|P|$ is not divisible by $p$; that is, such that $|HxP|$ is divisible by $p^a$ and no larger power of $p$, where $|P|=p^a$.

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin I think I see now. Does the following work? I pick $x$ that is in $P$, where $P$ is a sylow $P$ group of $G$. This gives me that the intersection is a subgroup and moreover, as $|HxP|\leq |G|$ it means that the left-hand side (in the inequality in the question) is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: If $x\in P$, then $HxP = HP$, so $|HP| = |H||P|/|H\cap P|$, and your expression on the left is just $|H|/|H\cap P|$. There is no reason to assume that this expression is not divisible by $p$; in fact, it may very well be divisible by $p$ (e.g., if $H$ is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ with $H\neq P$, then this will *definitely* be divisible by $p$). And if by "inequality in question" you meant $|HxP|\leq|G|$, then this is also false, since $P\leq HxP$ when $x\in P$ (or $x\in H$), and so $HxP$ will be disibiel by $p^a$.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I explained my self properly. Is not true that for such an $x$ we have $\frac{|HxP|}{|P|}$ being not disivible by $p$?  I know that $p^a$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $G$ and I know that $|HxP| \leq |G|$.

Comment: I **explicitly** said that this is not the case. Knowing $|HxP|\leq|G|$ doesn't tell you any such thing. Why would it? And I also told you how to construct a counterexample. If you need something explicit, take $G=S_3$, $p=2$, $P=\{e,(12)\}$, and $H=\{e,(13)\}$, Here $a=1$. If you take $x\in P$, then $HxP = \{e,(13),(12),(123)\}$, which has order $4$; so $|HxP|/|P| =\frac{4}{2} = 2$. Is that divisible by $2$? Of course it is.

Comment: Apologies, I think I see now. The issue for me was that I thought that $HP$ would also be a subgroup. I will think about this question more.